# Sort behaves strange for negative numbers with absolute value below one

Tags: regex, sorting, vim

Could someone explain me why in vim

```
:% !sort -ngk1
```

applied to

```
-1.3
0.002
0.1
-0.0021
0.2
-0.1
-0.15
```

gives:

```
-1.3
-0.0021
-0.1
-0.15
0.002
0.1
0.2
```

? How can I change this? Or is this a real bug in sort?

I could post a lot of such examples where the output is even more confusing (e.g. even mixed signs). It seems that this errors only occure for values below one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, both `sort -nk1` and `sort -gk1` (sort 8.20 complains about `options '-gn' are incompatible` when both are given) give the correct order. (Also, this probably has nothing to do with Vim, as you're invoking the external `sort` command.)

My best guess is that you're using a *locale* with a different *decimal point* (e.g. in German, it's `0,42` instead of `0.42`). Try:

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 sort -nk1 file
```

Comment: Indeed this gives the correct result which I of course can write to a new file. But for some reason it's not working inside of vim even though I fixed LC_ALL before opening the file.

Comment: Try `:echo $LC_ALL` from Vim. You can also try to change it there: `:let $LC_ALL = 'en_US.UTF-8'`. Or `:language C`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `-n` and `-g` options are incompatible.  Try instead

```
:% !sort -nk1
```

This seems to do what you want.

Comment: Well actually I tryed this first but the results is the same.

Comment: I see.  I seem to get a different result.  I seem to get the correct result.  If relevant, when I type `sort --version`, I read `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.13`.  If this is indeed a bug in your `sort`, that's regrettable.